# using bundle to pass data between fragment to another fragment example

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have 3 sherlockListFragments in my app. Every fragment has some editTexts and the last fragment has a button which when it's pressed all data in the first and second fragments should be accessed and stored.
I used bundle to send data between fragments. with the simple following example,
This is the code of my first fragment :

```
public class PersonalDataFragment extends SherlockListFragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmet_personal_data, container, false);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    PersonalDataFragment fragment = new PersonalDataFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("y", "koko"); //any string to be sent
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}
and this is the code of the fragment that receives the text :

```
public class WorkExpRefFragment extends SherlockListFragment  {
String myInt;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workexp_ref, container, false);


    final EditText t = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    final Button generate = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            t.setText(myInt + "sadfigha");
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(getArguments()!=null) {
        myInt = getArguments().getString("y");
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Now I have a null in the third fragment, what should i do ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's normal that your code fails. In the first fragment all you do is create a new instance of `PersonalDataFragment` and you pass it a `Bundle` with the data. The problem is although *fragment*  holds the data in the `Bundle`, the fragment itself is not the one used by the app(isn't even attached to the `Activity`). You also set the `Bundle` on a `PersonalDataFragment` instance but you try to access the data in a `WorkExpRefFragment` which will obvious not work as the two fragments don't have a direct connection.

One simply solution for what you want to do is to let the `Activity` "save" the data for your fragments as the `Activity` is available for all fragments. First create two methods in the `Activity` holding the three fragments:

```
public void saveData(int id, Bundle data) {
    // based on the id you'll know which fragment is trying to save data(see below)
    // the Bundle will hold the data
}

public Bundle getSavedData() {
    // here you'll save the data previously retrieved from the fragments and
    // return it in a Bundle
}
```

Then your fragments will save their data like this:

```
public class PersonalDataFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

   // this will identify the PersonalDataFragment fragment when trying to save data 
   public void static int id PERSONAL_ID = 1; 
   //...

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString("y", "koko"); //any string to be sent
      YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) getActivity();
      activity.saveData(PERSONAL_ID, bundle);
   }    
}
```

To retrieve the data in the `WorkExpRefFragment` fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) getActivity();
    Bundle savedData = activity.getSavedData();
}
```

Depending on how you used those fragments this solution might not work. Also, keep in mind that the `Bundle` you pass like above will not be retained for a configuration change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It works for me but i need it to get the data when the button (in third frag.) is presses not when the first frag. is created. i want it to be retained for a configuration change.
So, what should i do ?

Comment: I got it and made addTextChanged listiner :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I have faced a similar scenario.**

And Fragment Result API solved my case.

Check the docs [Get results using the Fragment Result API](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result)